# Cannot select options for has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan, rails-admin

I am using rails_admin, devise, and cancan.

Users have many roles.

I have an admin page set up where a user with the admin role can manage users. However, admins cannot manage roles.

When creating or editing users, roles are not listed.

How do I allow admins to add roles to a user without letting them edit or create roles?

this is my ability file

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize user
    if user && user.admin?
      can :access, :rails_admin
      can :dashboard
      cannot :manage, Role
      can :manage, User
    else
      cannot :access, :rails_admin
    end
  end
end
```

I tried explicitly overriding the association scope in the rails_admin config, but that didn't help at all:

```
  field :role do
    associated_collection_scope do
      Proc.new do |scope|
        scope = scope
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by adding `can :index, Role` but that isn't really desired as it makes Roles show up in the sidebar.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize user
    if user && user.admin?
      can :access, :rails_admin
      can :dashboard
      can :index,  Role
      can :manage, User
    else
      cannot :access, :rails_admin
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Adding Roles to `config.excluded_models` in `rails_admin.rb` hid the unwanted index pages & navigation items.